# Rails - Comparison on the last 3 updated records of Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having issue with a comparison in Ruby on Rails. I want to check if a fullname is the last 3 updated records in the database. For some reason it checks the whole database.

```
if Playlist.where(fullname: @last_fullname).order(updated_at: :desc).limit(3).exists?
  puts "records exists in last 3 updated records"
else
  puts "record not found"
end
```

Not sure if the syntax is correct or should be broken up. It doesn't give me an error but the result is not what is expected.

EDIT: the expected result is that when a record is not within the last 3 updated then it should give "record not found". If the record is within the last 3 updated it should give "record exists in last 3 updated records".

What I'm getting when the @last_fullname exists in the database is that it will always give "records exists in last 3 updated records" eventhough it's not in the last 3 updated.

I'm only getting "record not found" when it doesn't exits in the database.

Any idea?

Comment: please show us the actual result and the expected result.

Comment: You should search for the `full_name` outside of the 3 last record query, not in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this at database level only with subqueries: select last 3 records and from those last 3 records search for fullname. What your example query does is search for all records with the given fullname and sorts by updated_at. Given that you only require 3 records you could do this in user space:

```
Playlist.order(updated_at: :desc).limit(3).any?{ |playlist| playlist.fullname == @last_fullname }
```

Comment: Thanks @bcd for the explanation. This solved the issue.